# How to enable htaccess on localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm running my website on my local server and using mamp on my mac machine.

Was just wondering what do i have to do to allow the url redirections on my htaccess file to be read on my local server as per how it works on my live site.

I managed to move my .htaccess file into my local host root which is: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs.

But when i try running: localhost:8888/products, i get a no found error.

```
        RewriteEngine on
        ##RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^everything-under.sg$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.everything-under.sg/$1 [L,R=301]

        RewriteRule    ^products?$                                      pages/list.php                                      [NC,L]
        ...
```

I was just wondering if i'm missing something that results in the .htaccess not being detected and working. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: In Windows, I use WAMP Server and I need to enable the "rewrite module" if I want to use my own .htaccess redirections. Maybe you need to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a fresh installation of MAMP 3.0.7 and the .htaccess and the mod_rewrite module is enabled on default on /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

In any case, you should be checking if the following lines are in your "/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf" file.  First make sure the mod_rewrite module is uncommented.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

The "AllowOveride All" allows the use of the .htaccess file in the httpd config file.

```
<Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">

    # .....

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #.....

</Directory>
```

According to your current mod_rewrite rules, localhost:8888/products would be 301 redirected to http://www.everything-under.sg/products.  Is that the intention?